# Как связать пользовательское свойство со столбцом в бд

Tags: php, битрикс

Как связать созданное пользовательское свойство в инфоблоке со столбцом в базе данных?

Comment: Это слишком общий вопрос. Пользовательское свойство уже под капотом является столбцом в некоей таблице в базе данных.

Answer (score 0):

Общий ответ: создайте собственный тип свойств. Пример рассмотрен на странице курса https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2832